# How to save and load model from unsupervised learning?

Tags: clustering, machine-learning-model

[Beginner]

Sorry if this is dumb question.

I am following the model from this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/k-medoids-clustering-on-iris-data-set-1931bf781e05) and below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# Dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = pd.DataFrame(iris.data,columns = iris.feature_names)

target = iris.target_names
labels = iris.target

#Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(data), columns=data.columns)

#PCA Transformation
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(data)
PCAdf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2','principal component 3'])

datapoints = PCAdf.values
m, f = datapoints.shape
k = 3

#Visualization
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 6))
ax = Axes3D(fig, elev=-150, azim=110)
X_reduced = datapoints
ax.scatter(X_reduced[:, 0], X_reduced[:, 1], X_reduced[:, 2], c=labels,
          cmap=plt.cm.Set1, edgecolor='k', s=40)
ax.set_title("First three PCA directions")
ax.set_xlabel("principal component 1")
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_ylabel("principal component 1")
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_zlabel("principal component 1")
ax.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels([])
plt.show()

def init_medoids(X, k):
   from numpy.random import choice
   from numpy.random import seed

   seed(1)
   samples = choice(len(X), size=k, replace=False)
   return X[samples, :]

medoids_initial = init_medoids(datapoints, 3)

def compute_d_p(X, medoids, p):
   m = len(X)
   medoids_shape = medoids.shape
   # If a 1-D array is provided, 
   # it will be reshaped to a single row 2-D array
   if len(medoids_shape) == 1: 
       medoids = medoids.reshape((1,len(medoids)))
   k = len(medoids)

   S = np.empty((m, k))

   for i in range(m):
       d_i = np.linalg.norm(X[i, :] - medoids, ord=p, axis=1)
       S[i, :] = d_i**p

   return S

S = compute_d_p(datapoints, medoids_initial, 2)


def assign_labels(S):
   return np.argmin(S, axis=1)

labels = assign_labels(S)

def update_medoids(X, medoids, p):

   S = compute_d_p(datapoints, medoids, p)
   labels = assign_labels(S)

   out_medoids = medoids

   for i in set(labels):

       avg_dissimilarity = np.sum(compute_d_p(datapoints, medoids[i], p))

       cluster_points = datapoints[labels == i]

       for datap in cluster_points:
           new_medoid = datapoints
           new_dissimilarity= np.sum(compute_d_p(datapoints, datap, p))

           if new_dissimilarity < avg_dissimilarity :
               avg_dissimilarity = new_dissimilarity

               out_medoids[i] = datap

   return out_medoids

def has_converged(old_medoids, medoids):
   return set([tuple(x) for x in old_medoids]) == set([tuple(x) for x in medoids])

#Full algorithm
def kmedoids(X, k, p, starting_medoids=None, max_steps=np.inf):
   if starting_medoids is None:
       medoids = init_medoids(X, k)
   else:
       medoids = starting_medoids

   converged = False
   labels = np.zeros(len(X))
   i = 1
   while (not converged) and (i <= max_steps):
       old_medoids = medoids.copy()

       S = compute_d_p(X, medoids, p)

       labels = assign_labels(S)

       medoids = update_medoids(X, medoids, p)

       converged = has_converged(old_medoids, medoids)
       i += 1
   return (medoids,labels)

results = kmedoids(datapoints, 3, 2)
final_medoids = results[0]
data['clusters'] = results[1]

#Count
def mark_matches(a, b, exact=False):
   """
   Given two Numpy arrays of {0, 1} labels, returns a new boolean
   array indicating at which locations the input arrays have the
   same label (i.e., the corresponding entry is True).

   This function can consider "inexact" matches. That is, if `exact`
   is False, then the function will assume the {0, 1} labels may be
   regarded as the same up to a swapping of the labels. This feature
   allows

     a == [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
     b == [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

   to be regarded as equal. (That is, use `exact=False` when you
   only care about "relative" labeling.)
   """
   assert a.shape == b.shape
   a_int = a.astype(dtype=int)
   b_int = b.astype(dtype=int)
   all_axes = tuple(range(len(a.shape)))
   assert ((a_int == 0) | (a_int == 1) | (a_int == 2)).all()
   assert ((b_int == 0) | (b_int == 1) | (b_int == 2)).all()

   exact_matches = (a_int == b_int)
   if exact:
       return exact_matches

   assert exact == False
   num_exact_matches = np.sum(exact_matches)
   if (2*num_exact_matches) >= np.prod (a.shape):
       return exact_matches
   return exact_matches == False # Invert

def count_matches(a, b, exact=False):
   """
   Given two sets of {0, 1} labels, returns the number of mismatches.

   This function can consider "inexact" matches. That is, if `exact`
   is False, then the function will assume the {0, 1} labels may be
   regarded as similar up to a swapping of the labels. This feature
   allows

     a == [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
     b == [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

   to be regarded as equal. (That is, use `exact=False` when you
   only care about "relative" labeling.)
   """
   matches = mark_matches(a, b, exact=exact)
   return np.sum(matches)

n_matches = count_matches(labels, data['clusters'])
print(n_matches,
     "matches out of",
     len(data), "data points",
     "(~ {:.1f}%)".format(100.0 * n_matches / len(labels)))
```

How can I save the above model after training without having to rerun the above code every time a new record that has not been assigned a cluster is added to the data set?

I have also streamlined the code on my local machine to comment out all visualizations and everything after the `#Count` and am still able to get cluster assignments on my dataset. Just dont want to run the above code everytime we get a new record.

I can save and load a model post training with Keras/Tensorflow, not sure if I have to use only those tools to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very familiar with k-medoids, but i guess it's something like k-means, right? If so, the most time-consuming part of the entire model is **updating the medoids**. We randomly select initial start and update the center of mass to have better cluster results.

I suggest you to **pickle** `final_medoids`. When you have new data, compute the pca, pass it to `kmedoids` function with the pickled `final_medoids` as starting medoids. Then you can use following functions to compute score or something. There might be some tenical errors, but i think the main idea is to save the steady medoids so that we don't need a lot of time for updating.

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for and your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you so much